# attack on contact form

Tags: php, forms, http-post, spam-prevention

I have a simple contact form with the following security features:

1. Captcha in the form of a math equation (with javascript)
2. Hidden input text to serve as a honeypot for bots
3. I log each submission (time and submitter's IP) in a db table and do not allow the same IP to resubmit the form for a period of 2h.

However, despite this I am being bombed from the same IP address with form submissions. OK you can crack the Captcha and also the hidden input field, but how is it that someone can submit the form without their IP being written to the db and then be blocked?

I have the following layout (for brevity I am not posting the actual code but am just providing the logical structure - I can post the actual code if needed):

```
if ($_POST  && captcha correct)
    if (honeypot filled) {
       -> discard
    } else {
       if(IP exists in db) {
           if (last submission was less than 2h ago){
               -> block submission and display error message
           } else {
               -> allow submission and update timestamp in db
           }
       } else { // (IP does not exist in db)
           -> allow submission and add IP and timestamp to db
       }
    }
}
```

So I am only allowing the submission (i.e, the sending of an email to myself containing the content of the form) if it passes the IP check. And yet, I have submissions every few seconds or so from the same IP (I know this because I include the $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] in the email to myself) WITHOUT the IP getting entered into the db (and blocked). How is this possible and what can I do to fix this?
I have tested the feature for manual submissions of the form and it works.Thanks.

Comment: Your If-Else looks good. Could be an issue with timestamp comparison. Other than that not seeing any issues with this info which is provided.

Comment: @Keral: I tried it with manual submissions and the time comparison seems OK, i.e., I am blocked from resubmitting the form for 2h. So the attacker must have found a way to bypass this. I am just at a loss as to how this can be done.

Comment: You have the post body, right? Just post it yourself and see what happens.

Comment: @Pete If you are blocked then it means your code posted above works as you wanted it to work. Now how attacker is bypassing it can be said if you provide more info. Do you use some include file? Is anything directly accessible? Do you have any other testing files lying around? etc.

Comment: @pguardiario: sorry but I am not sure I follow.

Comment: @Keral: yes I have some include files: (1) a config file with some variable declarations, and (2) the phpmailer class definition files . Actually, the form is displayed on all my pages in the sidebar, so there may be other includes as well. However, the attacker is hopping through all my pages to submit the form, so it is not limited to a particular page. I have now blocked the entire IP range of the attacker's provider (Russian) in htaccess as they have not responded to my email reporting the abuse. Still, I would like to know how this works so I can prevent it without blocking IP ranges.

Comment: I'm saying that he posted a payload that got around your logic. Post that same payload and set breakpoints so you can see where your logic failed.